# multi thread receiver in single socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server, client

With TCP, I'm designing some programs like next.

clients' recv in many threads are waiting for one server's send message. However, there is a condition. recv is waiting for a specific send message.

For example

client

```
thread 1: recv (key = 4)
thread 2: recv (key = 6)
thread 3: recv (key = 9)
```

server

```
send(value = A) for key 4 - send(value = B) for key 9 - send(value = C) for key 6
```

then, thread 1 should get value A, thread 3 should get value B, thread 2 should get value C

how can recv function **distinguish** server send messages? Is there any good idea or solution?
Thanks.

Comment: @Cacahuete Frite thx. then, can you recommend some model or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` doesn't support content-filtered data receiving.

You should distinguish those kind of messages on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In practice, can you recommend any good model or solution?

Comment: @lemni You could make one thread that receives the messages and then sends them to the correct thread. Or you could process all the messages in one thread.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for your advice. I wonder the meaning of the second sentence, does it means that one thread recv it and forward to correct thread?